# Html.ActionLink generating URL with controller and action as query parameters

Tags: asp.net

Using Asp.net 5.2.6 I've added a new Register Action to my AuthController, and trying to generate an ActionLink on my Login page. No matter what I do the URL is coming out as

```
http://host/?action=Register&controller=Auth
```

But I'm expecting

```
http://host/Auth/Register
```

I've tried attribute routing, and adding a specific mapping in RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // Web Forms default
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "WebFormDefault",
        "",
        "~/Default.aspx"
    );

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Tried with and without this
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Registration",
        "Auth/Register",
        new { controller = "Auth", action = "Register" });

    // MVC Default
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

My new action methods in AuthController are below. The rest of AuthController is just the Get & Post Login Actions.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register()
{

    return View("Register", new Register());
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(Register register)
{

    // validation here
    ...
    return View("Register", register);

}
```

This is how I'm constructing my link, I've also tried the shorter method signatures for the same.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register Now", "Register", "Auth", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

I'm utterly confused by this, I've never had this trouble in the past. Please help!

Comment: When you click the URL, do you end up at the desired view?

Comment: What happened if you remove `routes.MapPageRoute`? Did you use other custom routing definition in `RouteConfig`?

Comment: @mason No I get bounced to the Index page.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I added the MapRoute to see if it would help, without it I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of this code your have :

```
// Tried with and without this
routes.MapRoute(
    "Registration",
    "Auth/Register",
    new { controller = "Auth", action = "Register" });
```

Either remove this, or put it at the very end - after the MVC Default.

Comment: as per the comment, I've tried with and without, and the route is working perfectly, just the URL isn't being generated correctly.

Comment: I am so sorry - I meant remove  the MapPageRoute code. Or put it at the very end of the routes. I was able to replicate this error by adding this before the default route in the Route.Config.
  routes.MapPageRoute(
        "WebFormDefault",
        "",
        "~/Default.aspx"
    );